# Change background position based on device orientation

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this trick where when using a smart phone on portrait you get this background on your webpage:

[image: portrait you get this background on your webpage]

And then when on landscape mode the image would have a wider look like this:

[image: And then when on landscape mode the image would have a wider look like this]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, it would be helpful if you can provide an example of the code that you are trying to help the community answer.

Comment: I agree you should post code, but also - your question was actually clear - which is rare...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be thorough, there are many ways you could do this. JavaScript may be more helpful in certain situations where you are setting the img source. That said, in most cases, you'll want to use CSS. You can read about all of your CSS options here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

```css
body {
  background: url(https://placehold.it/500x1000);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    background: url(https://placehold.it/1000x2000);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background: url(https://placehold.it/2000x3000);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- body tag is included by default... -->

<!-- hey StackSnippet warriors(trolls)... key example here of a bad time to use it -->
```

Comment: Preemptive strike.

Answer (score 1):

Im sorry if i havent posted any code.. but thanks sherrifderek i have achieved what i wanted without using media queries by just using

```
body {
background: url(../img/intro-bg2.jpeg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
   -moz-background-size:cover;
     -o-background-size:cover;
        background-size:cover;
background-position:center top; /*****Just added this*****/
}
```

I m not sure if il run into any problems, if you guys have any inputs/help to code this better, itll be appreciated. thank you!

EDIT: turns out i had to use

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
 body {
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:center top;
 }
}
```

to get what i want to work on landscape

Comment: Glad you were able to get things going. You should check out Autoprefixer and CSS processors. It will allow you to write your CSS without all of the vendor prefixes. Keeping clear indentation will really help too. : )